# Don't want window['slider'].Update to trigger an event in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

When I click on the "Add Apple" button, the events "Add Apple" and "slider" are triggered.
I guess that is because `window['slider'].Update(range=(0, 0))` triggers the slider to update and thus triggers the event.

How can I **not** make the "slider" event trigger? But I still want the slider to update the range.

Could this be a bug? Because similarly, `window['combo'].Update("Add Apple")` does not trigger the "combo" event as printed by `print(event,"event")`.

Python 3.10.13
PySimpleGUI 4.60.5

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
layout = [
    [sg.Combo([], default_value='', key='combo', size=(30, 15), enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Slider(range=(1, 10), size=(30, 15), orientation='h', key='slider', enable_events=True)],
    [sg.Button('Add Apple')]
]
window = sg.Window('Combo Box Example', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    print(event,"event")
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Add Apple':
        values['combo'] = "Add Apple"
        window['combo'].Update("Add Apple")
        window['slider'].Update(range=(0, 0))
    elif event == 'slider':
        print("slider is slided")
window.close()
```

Comment: I'd just declare bool flag `is_user_triggered = True` and unset after `.update()` call, then check it inside `slider` event and set back after.

Comment: Something like [*this*](https://tio.run/##hZHfS8MwEMff@1eEvjSBMiYiiNCH@RNBVJjiwyglW25dMDYlSbfVf77ektkONjQP7YV87nvfu6tbt9LV@WVtuk5@1do48tpOMVLw8P5IuCW2jBRvdeNIRmYRwTOz5ehGf801neUpEbDkjXLFmqsGsiRJySe0WbLYAXix8hsyej5OydkFSwlUfK6ggDVUzmZvpgGWp73qVEkBhhpelZh0hjljdiShjcRk7qSusmT1W8/61OS/CteNc7qiyUQIMqmxy4TlUR5tZCX0BjtE5MPHNPEtkmu9JXdbvhsIiodJsCiStmgsmMIZWZZgQGDurla0WUkFPrzyRb2PlPjpWIRCpZEBLijzhP/URlaOBjj2vzi8ymWQIFkw9/hc3Dy9TO9ug/zuzFHsMxRTh/hBkwMcjMz2@8nRUdxjcU8Flz01eq8Fd0APUHbE7jfQw/st4trGbKBPDe6eKwunGthLDu7x9UhgeB0GGYdMhImPRPy3g7C6sJqF0hYo67of).

Comment: @OlvinRoght
Thanks, I add a flag to track this changes.